# Is letting mypy handle typechecking a good practice in python?

Tags: python, mypy, typing

Say I have a function:

```
from typing import Union

def foo(bar: Union[float, list]):
    if type(bar) == float:
        bar = [bar]

    return [baz(i) for i in bar]
```

The question is that technically, I left part of typechecking for the typehints, which are not evaluated by python, but by whatever static typechecker I'm using.

Should I have been verbose with something like:

```
def foo(bar: Union[float, list]):
    if type(bar) == float:
        bar = [bar]
    elif type(bar) == list:
        pass
    else
        raise TypeError

    return [baz(i) for i in bar]
```

This one has really ugly (and maybe bad practice) `pass` statement.

Not only that, both will cause a mypy error that I'm tring to iterate over `bar`, but since its type is an union with `float`, float is not iterable.

What is the best practice to handle this family of coding patterns?

Comment: You don't need the `pass` if you change your `elif`condition to `type(bar) != list` and the block to `raise TypeError`. Also you don't need the `else`part then since it will either change `bar`to a list or raise an error. Further, checking for types is better done using [ìsinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) rather than comparison and `type()`

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. And what about implicit typechecking with static typing linters vs explicit typechecking with python code?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should avoid explicit type checking as much as possible that only raises an exception. Any type can be passed if it does not cause an error, and if it does, it is redundant to raise the error yourself. This rule fits well with duck typing, one of the basic philosophies of Python.

For example, consider the case where `bar` is a `tuple`. It behaves exactly the same as `list`, so there should be no harm passing it through. The same might be true for a custom object that implements `__iter__`. So what you really need to check is not its type, but whether it is iterable or not:

```py
def foo(bar: Union[float, list]):
    if not isinstance(bar, typing.Iterable):  # Be aware that str is also Iterable.
        bar = [bar]

    return [baz(i) for i in bar]
```

However, there are three exceptions that I often make (These are based on my experience).

1. When it does not cause an error, but results in unintended behavior.
2. When it causes an error, but it takes a long time to get there.
3. When it causes an error, but you can provide more intuitive error messages.

Comment: This will result in a mypy error that you are trying to iterate over bar which is not iterable - it's the same issue as it is with mine, that's why I'm asking a proper way to do it.